# Why does ReplaceWith() not work on variables that contain HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a variable which contains a span element like this:

```
$elem.find("img, img + span").each(function(innerIndex) {
    var $figcaption = $(this).next('span')
```

I want to replace the `<span>` tag inside this variable with a `<figcaption>` tag instead. I tried using `ReplaceWith()` but it won't allow it on a variable.

How can I do the replacement within the variable? I am not manipulating the DOM directly at this stage.

Comment: its replaceWith() , not ReplaceWith()

Comment: Can you show the full example of how you're invoking `replaceWith`?

Comment: `replaceWith()` is jQuery API which works on jQuery object not on strings, on strings use `replace`

Comment: @vinayakj it isn't a string in there, its actually an object

Comment: Well I was trying to just keep it simple. However, the replaceWith() does not work. Thanks for the downvote

Comment: I didnt downvote JFYI, keeping simple doesnt mean changing object to string, which invalidates the below answers now.

Comment: I want to change the contents of the variable, not the dom

Answer (score 1):

if you need it like

```
<span>
    <figcaption>
         Copyright information
    </figcaption>
 </span>
```

you can try **.html()**

```
var $figcaption = '<span>Copyright information</span>';
$($figcaption).html('<figcaption>'+ $($figcaption).text()+'</figcaption>');
```

if you need it like

```
<figcaption>
     Copyright information
</figcaption>
```

you can *(use replaceWith())*

```
var $figcaption = '<span>Copyright information</span>';
$($figcaption).replaceWith('<figcaption>'+ $($figcaption).text()+'</figcaption>');
```

to change the variable

```
var $figcaption = '<span>Copyright information</span>';
$figcaption = $figcaption.replace(/span/g , 'figcaption');
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/b8m7vohy/)

Comment: This is changing the DOM, but not the contents inside the $figcaption var. I am trying to later add $figcaption to another element but it hasn't changed from `<span>`. How do I fix that? I want to do something like this: `$contents = $(this).add($figcaption);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `replace()`; consider the following:

```
var $figcaption = '<span>Copyright information</span>';
// Replace the opening and closing span tags
$figcaption = $figcaption.replace("<span>", "<figcaption>").replace("</span>", "</figcaption>");
```

Comment: no need to use separate replace for opening and closing tags, can be done using single replace

Comment: THis doesn't work either. It says TypeError  $figcaption.replace is not a function

Comment: @volumeone it works for me... what are you doing different?

Comment: The answer is correct considering OP's previous code which contained string not object

Comment: @volumeone Well someone did, sorry for accusing you